# SimpleXML XML Parsing

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have created a script that take XML from URL and updates mysql database and parses data to csv file.

I get HTML strings in XML and they should not be there. How to remove them while parsing?

I load XML file like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(utf8_encode($xml_url), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Error that I get when running the script:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://domain.com/api/get_catalog.php?id=351&user=878&key=b8:1: parser error : Space required after the Public Identifier in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://domain.com/api/get_catalog.php?id=351&user=878&key=b8:1: parser error : SystemLiteral " or ' expected in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://domain.com/api/get_catalog.php?id=351&user=878&key=b8:1: parser error : SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /dokumenti/skripte/xmlupdate/lost/test/lost_xml.php on line 59
xml $ not loaded.
```

When I use a Firefox and save XML from url to disk I have no problem parsing it just when I try to get it from url.

XML looks fine:
Part of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecroKatalog>
<viewCustomerDiscount>
    <BrojArtikla>10214</BrojArtikla>
    <Naziv>Eksterno kucište 2.5&quot; S-ATA+IDE HDD, Aluminium, USB 2.0</Naziv>
    <NetoPrice>81.8224</NetoPrice>
    <Status>Dostupno</Status>
    <Opis></Opis>
    <dugi_opis>Isporucuje se u SIVOJ boji</dugi_opis>
    <Image>http://shop.lost.hr/data/images/big/10.jpg</Image>
    <WEB_Grupa>Ladice i eksterna kucišta - OSTALO</WEB_Grupa>
    <Akcija>0</Akcija>
    <Proizvodjac></Proizvodjac>
    <Klasifikacija>PH-25SD-B/VK220</Klasifikacija>
</viewCustomerDiscount>
```

Comment: Because it's not valid xml.

Comment: looks like additional lines are appended to your XML when you call it remotely and that causes it invalid

Comment: First you can use XMLReader::isValid(void) to see if your xml document is valid or not.

Comment: I have tried XMLReader::isValid(void) and got bool(true) so XML is valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some **HUGE** clues in the error messages.  It is complaining about seeing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

It is the start of a HTML document being provided by that website… not the XML you're looking for.

This usually happens when you have to authenticate against the remote service (hence working in your browser, as you logged in), but you're not telling SimpleXML to do that for you.

Comment: I figured it's related to his statement: *"It stopped to work today and I am confused, as it reads HTML not XML"*. But that doesn't really help us.

Comment: But when I go to that url with browser I get valid XML?
3 hours ago this worked? And it was working past 20 days how?

Comment: @mehnihma What url?......

Comment: @mehnihma Something changed; if you didn't change the code, go ask the API provider for support.

Comment: I will but I can do it tomorrow and I need it today,
I have tried file_get_contents and file_put_contents to download it and I get 404 page

Comment: I have solved it, it was a problem with my database on shared hosting server and also a problem with server api. Now it works after I have restored from backup

Comment: @mehnihma: what was your problem in server database? How you managed to solve it? Iam facing the same issue...

Comment: Depends on your problem, I had mistyped some queries